# Logging module prints logs on same line in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I must be missing something here because the log prints on the same line. I thought that logging module automatically creates new line?

```
temp = int(2489)
        logging.basicConfig(    filename='temp.log',
                                filemode='a',
                                format='%(asctime)s\n:%(message)s',
                                datefmt = '%s',
                                level=logging.DEBUG )

        logging.info(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Same happens with basic example:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="example.log")
logging.debug("This message should go to the log file")
logging.info("So should this")
logging.warning("And this, too")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was about to give up and just write to a file the old fashioned way when I realised the problem was not python related.

The line breaks were there but Notepad simply did not show them! Sublime Text 2 showed them just fine. So the solution is not to use Notepad as it simply does not work for non-windows created text files.